# find records starting with special characters using REGEXP in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Ok, so i am wanting to fetch results that start with a number and i have this regexp for finding only numerical entries

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE subject REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

but what if i want it to find numerical and all special character entries, how would i do that?

So for instance if a subject was ":subject" or ".subject" or "*subject" etc it would find them as well as "1subject" or "2subject" and so on...
Basically anything starting with something other than an aplhabetical character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use '`^[^a-zA-Z]`' as the regexp

What this means

First `^` is "anchor to the start of line"

`[` is start of a character class

`^` in the character class means negate this class - so match the opposite of the characters in it

`a-z` is all lower case english letters

`A-Z` is all upper case english letters

`]` is end of character class

As the class is on it's own it represents one character

So the regexp means "match any character at the start of a line that is not a-z or A-Z"
In the context of the SQL expression this should match any result that does not begin with a-z or A-Z

Comment: isn't that finding alphabetical only?

Comment: no - I've added an gloss on the meaning of the characters in the regexp.  Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation, really helps to understand what its actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex.  You want to find the subjects that start with A-Z or a-z.

```
WHERE (subject >= 'A' and subject < '[') OR (subject >= 'a' and subject < '{');
```

`[` is the next character after `Z` and `{` is the next character after `z`.

This will let the optimizer use any index on `subject` that you have.